# Using JQuery .on selector with table rows vs cells

Tags: jquery, events, html-table, jquery-selectors, row

I have searched and searched to no avail.

I'm creating a website that displays dynamically loaded content via AJAX.  So my base HTML has an empty table, and `<tr>`s are added on load.  As the `<tr>`s don't exist at document load time I can't attach a JQuery event to them, e.g. `$(tr).click(...)`.

I learnt the answer to get around this is to do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
        alert('node name = '+e.target.nodeName+', id='+e.target.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="rowID">
        <td id="cellID">One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the target returned by the event is the TD, not the TR.  So what am I doing wrong?

I know I could get around it with `e.target.parent.id`, but that's circuitous and doesn't help me learn.

Or is that just how it works?  Doesn't seem right to me, but perhaps someone can enlighten me?

Comment: Because the target clicked is a `td`, however the click event IS the `tr`. Change `e.target.nodeName` to `$(this).prop("tagName")` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: The click event is on the row, but the actual target is what you clicked on. No surprise that e.target returns the table cell.

Comment: Welcome to jQuery. Inside an elements event you can use `this` to refer to the element directly or `$(this)` to get it as a jQuery Object. In other words `this == element event is attached too`; `this.tagName == $(this).prop("tagName")` && `this.id == $(this).prop('id')`

Comment: Perfect!  Of course I can just use `this`!!  I use it on other events, but it never occurred to me I could use it with this `.on` event (perhaps because the event is attached to the table).  I was following examples on Codecademy, and they all use `e.target.id`, when they could have used `this.id`.
Thanks all, but especially @SpYk3HH, your explanation was clearest to me.

Comment: Also, impressive response times!  Kudos to all involved.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, it is just your  usage of the event.target, as others have mentioned the way that Javascript bubbles up events the target will always be the actual item you clicked.

jQuery provides you with the element that the click was fired on within the `this` object or `$(this)` if you want the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Its Because event.target, You can use jQuery(this).prop("tagName") and jQuery(this).attr("id") instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
        alert('node name = '+jQuery(this).prop("tagName")+', id='+jQuery(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="rowID">
        <td id="cellID">One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh.Thanks. I will take care of this from next time.

Comment: You can always hit the edit button and throw a quick explanation in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

the javascript bubbling is from the inside out, so when you click on a series of nested elements, the deepest element is the target, so basically yes, you have to use the method that you mentioned in order to get the tr as your target.

one other thing that you can do (but not in your situation) is to mask (using z-index) your element with the element that you want to be the target, so the inner element wouldn't get clicked, and the outer element is the one that actually is getting clicked.

one other thing that I need to add (as said in comments by others) is that you can refer to the `tr` in the `click` event of the tr using `this` or the jQuery way `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

The TD is the target because we are actually clicking on it... In Javascript the click event is bound to the parent and there children are affected. So when you click on the td his parent trigger the event.

Comment: No. All he has to do is use `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')`